# SQL query isn't working as it should be

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mySQL query:

```
SELECT
    mp.*
  , m.*
FROM missions_progress mp
LEFT JOIN missions m ON mp.mid = m.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT
     mid
   , uid
  FROM missions_progress mp
  WHERE uid = {$uid} AND mstatus = 'completed'
)
```

The issue is is that there are multiple rows in `'missions'` table, However if the player completes 1 mission, it doesn't load the other missions anymore.

Here's how the SQL query should work,

User opens missions.php page, and gets to see a list of missions they can do, if they start one, a row is inserted in mission_progress with mstatus = 'inprogress', if they completed this mission, the mstatus will be = 'completed' and the mission is finished. Taking them back to the mission page with the full missions list. However the last part isn't working, it says they've got 0 missions left, while there are at least 10+ rows in the missions table which they haven't done yet.

Is there anyone that could point me in the right direction?

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your subquery is not correlated (it doesn't depend on the current row) - so it will always return the same result. But I don't know how to fix it, since I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to display all available missions on the mission page right?

The question is not very clear and we would need sample data, but I'm going to do my best to answer you, using some simplified tables and random sample data.

If the mission is completed, it is not displayed. If it's not completed, it is displayed, along with the progress, right? And if a mission hasn't been begun yet, and have nothing in the missions_progress, it still needs to be displayed?

If that's the case, I think you are using an over complicated query. I would try something like this:

```
SELECT
    m.*,
    mp.*
FROM missions m
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
               FROM missions_progress
               WHERE uID = {$uid}) mp ON mp.mID = m.nID
WHERE Coalesce(mp.mStatus, '') != 'completed'
```

I have tried this with the following data:

missions:

```
ID  Name
--  -----
1   test1
2   test2
3   test3
4   test4
5   test5
```

mission_progress:

```
nID mID mStatus     uID
--- --- ----------- ---
1   1   in progress 1
2   3   in progress 1
3   3   completed   2
4   5   completed   1
```

I executed that for user #1, which completed mission 5 and has some progress for mission 1 and 3:

```
nID cName   nID  mID  mStatus     uID
--- -----   ---  ---  ----------- ---
1   test1   1    1    in progress   1
2   test2   NULL NULL NULL        NULL          
3   test3   2    3    in progress   1
4   test4   NULL NULL NULL        NULL
```

You can see that mission #5 didn't get pulled out as user 1 has completed it. the other 4 missions pulled out. Mission 1 and 3 had some progress, but weren't completed, so they pulled out.

The same query, for user #2, which completed mission # 3 and has no other progress:

```
nID cName   nID  mID  mStatus     uID
--- -----   ---  ---  ----------- ---
1   test1   NULL NULL NULL        NULL
2   test2   NULL NULL NULL        NULL
4   test4   NULL NULL NULL        NULL
5   test5   NULL NULL NULL        NULL
```

IF I understood your question correctly, I think this is what you'll need!

Comment: Sorry for the confusing message, but this is exactly what i've been looking for! Players can only do the mission once. When they completed that mission, it takes them back to the list of which missions they can do, and start another one. Thanks for the detailed information. Greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: No problem man! I haven't tested that out with hundreds of records, if you discover a problem with your testing, just hit me up!

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is is that there are multiple rows in 'missions' table,
>   However if the player completes 1 mission, it doesn't load the other
>   missions anymore.

That's because off

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT
     mid
   , uid
  FROM missions_progress mp
  WHERE uid = {$uid} AND mstatus = 'completed'
)
```

Your query properly needs to be more like. 
 But it's hard to say without example data and expected output.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    mp.*
  , m.*
FROM missions_progress mp
LEFT JOIN missions m ON mp.mid = m.id AND uid = {$uid} AND mstatus <> 'completed'
```

Comment: So the WHERE NOT EXISTS() is not required? Its meant to be that the player can only do the mission once, once they completed it, they can't do that mission anymore.

Comment: Ohw what you want missions that are not completed that would required `<>` operator instead.. Answer updated @Codemunkie

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the missions that someone hasn't done:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM missions m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM missions_progress mp
                  WHERE uid = {$uid} AND 
                        mp.mid = m.id AND
                        mp.mstatus = 'completed'
                 );
```

I don't think you really want columns from `missions_progress` in your result set.  If you do, then you might actually want:

```
SELECT m.*, mp.missions_status
FROM missions m LEFT JOIN
     missions_progress mp
     ON mp.mid = m.id AND uid = {$uid}
WHERE mp.mission_status IS NULL OR mp.mission_status <> 'completed';
```

If this is what you want, it is one of the few situations where you use a `WHERE` clause with a `LEFT JOIN` and include logic on the second table.